# Why is this jquery animation not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

ive been trying to get a sidebar to slide left and right depending on click.

I did try toggle could not get it to work.

I have now tried this code, it works when first clicked but once clicked for some reason it does not work when clicked again:

```
$('.pushbutton').on('click',function(){

        $('.left_sidebar, .footer').animate({left: "-320px"}, 800 );
        $('.main_body_right').animate({marginLeft: "25px"}, 800 );
        $('.pushbutton').animate({fontSize: "24px",fontWeight: "400",paddingTop: "3px"}, 500 );
        $('.pushbutton').html('+');
        $('.pushbutton').attr('class','pushbuttonplus');

    });

    $('.pushbuttonplus').on('click',function(){

        $('.left_sidebar, .footer').animate({left: "0px"}, 800 );
        $('.main_body_right').animate({marginLeft: "325px"}, 800 );
        $('.pushbuttonplus').animate({fontSize: "26px",fontWeight: "700",paddingTop: "0px"}, 500 );
        $('.pushbuttonplus').html('-');
        $('.pushbuttonplus').attr('class','pushbutton');

    });
```

Comment: put the example in: http://jsflidde.net/

Comment: Each time a ".pushbutton" is clicked, you seam to attach a new click event handler on all ".pushbuttonplus." elements which might lead to collisions between animations and performance issues

Comment: @f00bar .pushbutton is only used once, then the class attr is changed to pushbuttonplus so its only clicked once at a time before changing to another

Answer (score 3):

Because you are dynamically changing/adding/removing the class of the element, the selector will not be bound to any element.

Use [`event delegation`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead, so you'll event will be attached on the body, but only when a specific selector is matched.

Ref:

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up
>   to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to
>   outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that
>   path matching the selector.

Code:

```
$('body').on('click','.pushbutton', function () {

    alert("demo1")

    $('.left_sidebar, .footer').animate({
        left: "-320px"
    }, 800);
    $('.main_body_right').animate({
        marginLeft: "25px"
    }, 800);
    $('.pushbutton').animate({
        fontSize: "24px",
        fontWeight: "400",
        paddingTop: "3px"
    }, 500);
    $('.pushbutton').html('+');
    $('.pushbutton').attr('class', 'pushbuttonplus');

});

$('body').on('click','.pushbuttonplus', function () {

      alert("demo2")

    $('.left_sidebar, .footer').animate({
        left: "0px"
    }, 800);
    $('.main_body_right').animate({
        marginLeft: "325px"
    }, 800);
    $('.pushbuttonplus').animate({
        fontSize: "26px",
        fontWeight: "700",
        paddingTop: "0px"
    }, 500);
    $('.pushbuttonplus').html('-');
    $('.pushbuttonplus').attr('class', 'pushbutton');

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/wBBZm/

Answer (score 0):

Ive changed the logic of this and did this instead:

```
// Make the push sidebar push button functional
    $('.pushbutton a').on('click',function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        var currentId = $(this).attr('id');

        if(currentId == 'open_sidebar'){

            $('.left_sidebar, .footer').animate({left: "-320px"}, 800 );
            $('.main_body_right').animate({marginLeft: "25px"}, 800 );
            $('#open_sidebar').html('<a href="#">+</a>');
            $('#open_sidebar').attr('id','close_sidebar');

        }

        if(currentId == 'close_sidebar'){

            $('.left_sidebar').animate({left: "0px"}, 800 );
            $('.footer').animate({left: "40px"}, 800 );
            $('.main_body_right').animate({marginLeft: "325px"}, 800 );
            $('#close_sidebar').html('<a href="#">-</a>');
            $('#close_sidebar').attr('id','open_sidebar');

        }

    });
```

This seams to do the trick :)